# How to convert month number to roman?

Tags: python, django

Any ideia how to convert month number to roman ?

```
Eg: 4 => IV
```

I already get month number, i user
`date = datetime.date.today()`
`month = date.month`

For the next step, any ideia how to convert to roman number?

Thank you

Comment: There are only 12 months, a simple dict would do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should help:

```
# !pip install roman
import roman

# to roman
month = int(input('enter a month> ')) # 10
print(roman.toRoman(month))
```

The output as:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a good tutorial which can teach you how to convert integers to roman numerals: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-integer-to-roman/

In essence, we have to understand how roman numerals work, before converting the units, tens, hundreds, and thousands etc of the given number separately into roman numerals. Please look at the link for more details.

However, since you are only converting month to roman numerals, you can use a list containing the roman numerals from 1 to 12.

```
l = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX', 'X', 'XI', 'XII']
    
4_in_roman_numerals = l[4-1]
# Contains 'IV'
7_in_roman_numerals = l[7-1]
# Contains 'VII'
```